# skimage max image resolution (memoryerror)

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

At the moment i'm using scikit-image as a way to process my images in python. But after some testing I found out that scikit-image doesn't work with images which have a to high resolution. I tried to use a image with a resolution of 3024 x 4032 but it results in a MemoryError error. This happens on multiple different methods provided by scikit-image.

I've found out that it does work if I downscale the image to a way lower resolution. I want to know the maximum allowed resolution is so that I can downscale my images without losing too much of it's quality. And that I can check if a resolution is too big.

Answer (score 3):

I found the real cause of the problem. It's not the resolution but rather scikit-image who changes the datatype of the image to a float which makes it way too big for the memory stack.

A way to get around this is to turn your image in a numpy array with the datatype uint8. Like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

im = Image.open("test.jpg")
pix = np.array(im, dtype=np.uint8)
img = rgb2gray(pix)
```

after converting it to a numpy array, you can use it for any operation provided by scikit-image

Answer (score 2):

Your workaround is fine, but I would have done it like this:

```
from skimage import io
from skimage import img_as_ubyte

img = img_as_ubyte(io.imread('test.jpg', as_grey=True))
```